# itemEditEnd for FLex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex4.5

In version 4 there is a Flex itemEditEnd (in Datagrid) event, but does not exist in Flex 4.5, itemEditEnd this event has been replaced by what event?

Answer (score 0):

The MX DataGrid should not have changed; and according to the documentation, the [itemEditEnd](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event%3aitemEditEnd) is still there.

However, Flex 4.5 introduced a [DataGrid based on the Spark Architecture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html). This is a complete new component, and has many differences from the MX DataGrid.

You might look at the [gridItemEditorSessionSave](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#event%3agridItemEditorSessionSave) event as an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Data+Grid+Editing
I tried to use:

```
override public function save():void
{
   //data.dataField = value;
}
```

But I got error: "Incopatible override"

Any success at your side?

FIX,change **void** to **Boolean**, than in save() you can do pretty much the same stuff as in itemEditEnd in MX DataGrid:

```
override public function save():Boolean
{
   data.dataField = value;
   return true; //to save data to dataprovider
}
```

Example:

```
<s:GridItemEditor>
    <s:TextInput id="valueDisplay" width="100%"/>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
            override public function get value():Object
            {
                return valueDisplay.text;            
            }

            override public function set value(newValue:Object):void
            {
                valueDisplay.text = newValue.toString();
            } 

            override public function save():Boolean
            {
                data.dataField = value;
                return true;
            } 
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
</s:GridItemEditor>
```